# Openx plugin development

Tags: php, openx

I have just entered in the world of OpenX, and as figured out that new version is built with PLUGIN Framework. I have gone through the Openx plugin development documentation, but its quite bit complicated and half explained.

Being a php developer, I would like to jump into plugin development for openx.

If anyone can point me to a starting, with good reference and tutorial?

Thanks,
Tanmay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't got much reference but here is the link which can help you create plugins
https://svn.openx.org/openx/trunk/plugins_repo/release/openXDeveloperToolbox.zip

With this you can create a framework of plugin. This will be a great help to understand the file structure.

Hope some one will be helped

Comment: Thanks @jtanmay!  Wish I found this earlier, I was looking all over their repo for this!

Answer (score 1):

by using openX Developer Toolbox we we can create new mock plugins, basically it will create a new mock plugin files and you have to change those files as per requirement and you can install that plugin. It is not fully good solution for building a plugin but yes it will help you build a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another resource for plugins (includes a link to the Toolbox above as well as a demo plugin):

http://blog.openx.org/05/plugin-framework-exposed/

Answer (score 0):

Take care when using the plugin-skeleton generator. It will generate the function name of the delivery method with a wrong name. So at the end it will NOT be called at all.
Adding "_adRender" (as a postfix) to the function-name should fix this.